# Keep CSS animation when a Flash layer is placed over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I am using the [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) library as it supports safari whereas other packages, such as [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) don't. The way `ZeroClipboard` works is it places an invisible flash component over the button. Whilst this allows the button to keep its initial style set by the CSS, it does not allow it to use it style properties such as `cursor` and `:active`. You can see this <strike>below</strike> or on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/xxuaqz46/1/)

*Code snippet doesn't seem to be working with `ZeroClipboard`. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/xxuaqz46/1/) for working example*

```js
ZeroClipboard.config({swfPath: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.swf"});
var client = new ZeroClipboard($("#copyH"));
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

h1.copybtn {
  background: #4942ff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
h1.copybtn:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px #7f7aff;
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px #7f7aff;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px #7f7aff;
  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -4px);
  -moz-transform: translate(1px, -4px);
  -o-transform: translate(1px, -4px);
  transform: translate(1px, -4px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s !important;
  transition: all 0.25s !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.2.0/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<h1 class="copybtn" data-clipboard-text="Won't copy">Has effects working</h1>
<br>
<h1 id="copyH" class="copybtn" data-clipboard-text="Will copy">Has copy working</h1>
```

Is there a way that I can keep the functionality from the package and the CSS styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZeroClipboard has a class `.zeroclipboard-is-active` which would allow for this example to work correctly.

For example, the code could be re-written to

```
&:active, &.zeroclipboard-is-active {
  @include box-shadow(-1px -1px 4px #7f7aff);
  @include transform(translate(1px, -4px));
  @include transition(all 0.25s !important);
}
```

The documentation for this can be found [here](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#css-effects)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the styling on the flash object itself instead of the button. Or even on both using multiple selectors:

```
#global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge, #copyH { cursor:pointer; }
```

Not sure how the ids are generated, so you may want to be careful about that when figuring out how to write your css.

Comment: This was a pretty idea on how to do it but it turns out there is an inbuilt way of doing it. Thanks for the answer